# Ignore some javascript validations MVC3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, user-input, validation

I'm using MVC3 and I have a model like this:

```
public class Foo
{
 [Required]
 [Range(0.01, 99.99)]       
 public double? f1{ get; set; }
}
```

And I want to ugnore javascript range validation, but keep the required javascript validation.
How can I do that?

Comment: you can remove @html.validatefor() from your html code

Comment: but what about required? it wil be removed to.

Comment: yep there is a flaw in my logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution, just removed some attributes from textbox:

```
$('#fieldId').removeAttr("data-val-range");
$('#fieldId').removeAttr("data-val-range-min");
$('#fieldId').removeAttr("data-val-range-max");
```

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want the range validation then simply remove it

```
public class Foo
{
 [Required(ErrorMessage="This field is required")]      
 public double? f1{ get; set; }
}
```

---

### update:

to remove all validations on an input you can do

```
$("#f1").rules("remove");
```

for removing the range validation probably the following would work

```
$("#f1").rules("remove", "min max");
```

---

P.S this may not be the best practice...

Comment: I want to remove ONLY javascript validation and ONLY for range validator.

Comment: say if you disable the javascript validation with the `Range` validatior still in place and the user enters an out of range value the `ModelState.IsValid` will be false always...